# Adding multiple SQL queries to same Datagrid c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

So... I have a datagrid that I want to populate with the medication details selected in the combobox. I want to add a new row with the new medication selected from the combobox each time a button is clicked. I am running the below method in a button click event.

```
private void FillSalesItemGrid()
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {

                con.Open();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox_select_Item.Text.ToString()))
                {
                    sqlBuilder.Append("SELECT * FROM Medication WHERE MedName = @medName");
                    cParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@medName", comboBox_select_Item.Text.ToString()));
                }                

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlBuilder.ToString(), con);
                if (cParameters.Count != 0)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(cParameters.ToArray());
                }
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Medication");
                da.Fill(dt);

                dataGrid_saleItems.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
                sqlBuilder.Clear();
                cParameters.Clear();



            }
```

At the moment it displays the currently selected combobox item. It doesnt add a new "result" each time the button is clicked. I want it to work as if you were ringing up an item on a POS. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new Datatable each time you have to create it once and then fill it up with each function call (SqlDataAdapter.Fill does exactly that). 
That way you also only set the itemsource once.

Second solution would be to retrieve the current itemsource, convert it to a DataTable.
Someething like: DataTable table = (dataGrid_saleItems.ItemsSource as DataRowView).toTable()
If you continue with your code that will fill it up aswell.